Import files from external submodule
Is it possible to execute an external submodule of a project without changing the file content of the submodule itself?
Suppose I have this hierarchy.
mydir
 |
 +-- mya.py
 |
 +-- submodule
      |
      +-- subpackage
           |
           +-- __init__.py
           |
           +-- suba.py
           |
           +-- subb.py

submodule is an external git repository (cloned with git submodule add <git-repo> for what it's worth).
Inside this module, suba.py has an import statement of the kind from subpackage import subb.
Now, inside mya.py, what import statement should I use to correctly import submodule.subpackage.suba without changing the submodule code?
While I can insert
from submodule.subpackage import suba, at execution time it will raise the exception
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage'

You may need to add the submodule directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. Then you will be able to import subpackage, or as in this case, import objects from within subpackage.
Here is one possible alternative approach to achieve the same thing from within the script, if you don't want it to depend on setting the environment variable.
import os
import sys

thisdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(thisdir, "submodule"))

from subpackage import suba


Thanks, probably this is the best solution. I would like to add it to some __init__.py file, but I was wondering which is the best/recommended way. What I did, in order to not alter at all the submodule source, is: 1) I move mya.py to examples/mya.py; 2) create examples/__init__.py containing all but the last lines of your code; 2a) modyfy the join as join(thisdir, '..', 'submodule').
In this way, I can execute my code as python -m examples.mya. Is this recommended? Is there any drawback?

There are a couple of different things you can do. The thing that I always do and recommend is to use absolute imports instead of relative ones (you can learn more about them in the official documentation), e.g. from mydir.submodule.subpackage import suba. The reasons for that are simple:

They are easier to manage;
The code base looks cleaner and is easier to read.

So what you can do in your case is the following:

Make mydir a package by adding __init__.py file (you can omit this step but it will make your life easier as your code base grows, still make sure to keep your specific case in mind);
Import suba (or parts of it) via an absolute import (assuming that mydir corresponds to a src directory and contains your code):

import mydir.submodule.subpackage.suba
from mydir.submodule.subpackage import suba or
from mydir.submodule.subpackage.suba import func1



You can use the same strategy for every module in your application.
Another thing you can do is to build a local package/library from submodule since you don't want to make changes to it - this is basically what a library represents.
To build the package, you can do the following:

Download the subpackage source code (I would strongly recommend to keep it in a separate folder outside of your src directory but it's up to you);
Navigate to the folder and create a simple pyproject.toml file (more info here), e.g.:

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "submodule"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = [
  "dependency1",
  "dependency2"
]
requires-python = ">=3.8"


Build the package with python3 -m build (if you are using setuptools, I am familiar only with that build backend);
Copy the .tar.gz file in the project root, usually in a libs directory;
Install the package with pip install libs/subpackage-0.0.1.tar.gz (more info here).

I hope this helps!

The problem with building the package is that it is in active development, and I don't want to modify it nor reinstall the library with any minor update. That's why I wanted a cleaner solution that modifies the submodule source code as less as possible.
Also, for the first part. The problem is NOT that I cannot import the submodule files/modules/functions, but that those files themselves contain imports that are relative to the submodule root directory.
